# Draw over a custom ImageView dynamically

Tags: imageview

I'm working with a custom imageview, implementing pinch zoom, scroll, etc...

I need draw lines and dots over source image of this custom imageview, but this lines and dots need follow movement and scale (when zoomed). It would also be necessary to update this lines as some conditions in the code.

For example:

I have this custom imageview with a source image representing a map of my house, and i need draw a line from the entrance door to the bathroom, and a circle on the entrance door.

Anyone can help?